# Custom extensions for open file intent (forced extension)

Tags: android, android-intent

My code looks like following:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private fun selectExportDirectory(activity: FragmentActivity) {
    lastExportName = createNewExportFileName()
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = backupFileType
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, lastExportName)
    }
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, exportRequestCode)
}
```

**What I want**

I want to force the selection of a file with the extension `.backup`. The Intent takes care to adjust a user selected export file automatically if the file already exists and I want this behaviour as well.

**Problem**

- if I pass "application/zip" as `backupFileType` I can select "backup" or "backup.zip" as export file and android will create "backup.zip" file in both cases.
- if I pass "application/backup" as `backupFileType` I can select "backup" or "backup.backup" as well, but the extension won't be added automatically

Can I somehow adjust my code so that the user selected file always get's the extension `.backup`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to force the selection of a file with the extension .backup.

That is not possible, sorry. Not only does `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` not support this, but there is no requirement that a documents provider use file extensions. `EXTRA_TITLE` is used for a suggested "display name", and that does not have to wind up being used as a filename on a file.

> Can I somehow adjust my code so that the user selected file always get's the extension .backup?

You can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to have the user choose a tree, then create a document inside of that tree with whatever display name that you want. That display name can include a file extension sort of suffix. What the documents provider does with that display name is up to the provider; if it is the platform provider for the filesystem, that display name will turn into the filename.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:** You simply cannot define custom types which the OS doesn't know about.

**Solution:**
However, if you still want to do so, you need to make custom file picker with recycleview and pass the mount storage points and recursively iterate on all the file types:**(add filter of your extension)**

```
public void scanFiles(File file) {
File[] fileArray = file.listFiles(); 
for (File f : fileArray){
    if (f.isDirectory()) 
      scanFiles(f);
    if (f.isFile() && (f.getpath().endswith("..backup") || //any extensions)) {
        //Your custom file are here 
       }
    }
}
```